# Proof of a composition of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions such that $f\circ g$ is a quadratic function and $g$ is a linear function. Prove that $f$ is a quadratic function.

Comment: But what did you try?

Comment: Presumably $f$ and $g$ must be one variable functions, in which case you know that $(f \circ g)(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=dx+e$ for some constants $a,d\neq 0,b,c,e\in\mathbb C$

Comment: @Shuri2060 yes it is in one variable.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel well actually, the proof I tried is quite complicated to put here and I don't know if I have enough space to put it all.

Comment: @user463019 with what I've suggested above, I think using $(f\circ g)\circ g^{-1}=f$ will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**:

$g$ is linear $\implies g^{-1}$ is linear and $(f\circ g)\circ g^{-1}=f$ is quadratic.

---

Justifications:
$$y=ax+b\iff x=\frac1a y-\frac ba=a'y+b',$$

$$a(px+q)^2+b(px+q)+c=(ap^2)x^2+(2apq+bp)x+(aq^2+bq+c)=a'x^2+b'x+c'.$$

Answer (score 3):

For some constants, $a\neq0,b,c,d\neq0,e$,

$$(f \circ g)(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

$$g(x)=dx+e$$

and

$$g^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-e}{d}$$

Then

$$f(x)=\left((f\circ g)\circ g^{-1}\right)(x)=a{\left(\frac{x-e}{d}\right)}^2+b{\left(\frac{x-e}{d}\right)}+c$$

$$=\left(\frac{a}{d^2}\right)x^2+\left(\frac{bd-2ae}{d^2}\right)x+\left(\frac{cd^2-bde+ae^2}{d^2}\right)$$

$\implies f(x)=px^2+qx+r$ for some constants $p\neq0,q,r$.

$\implies f$ is quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, guys, I made out my proof but I don't know if it is correct. Let $(f\circ g)(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=mx+d$. So $f[g(x)]=f(mx+d)=ax^2+bx+c$.

I let $y=mx+d$ and $x=(y-d)/m$. Then I obtained the following:

$f(y)=a[(y-d)/m]^2+b[(y-d)/m]+c=[a(y^2-2yd+d^2)/m^2]+[(by-bd)/m]+c=(a/m^2)y^2+[(b/m-(2ad/m^2)]y+[(ad^2/m^2)-(bd/m)+c]=a_2y^2+a_1y+a_0$

Comment: 'Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$' assumes $f$ is quadratic before you start?

Comment: @Shuri2060 yes.

Comment: @user463019 But you have to prove that $f$ is quadratic. You can't start by assuming that.

Comment: @SahibaArora I edited the answer. See if it is alright now.

Comment: Now it is correct and exactly what Shuri2060 has done in her answer.